# Get global variable value PHP

Tags: globals

In twig, I can get the value this way,
`globalWebsite.freeTrialPeriodDays`

I need to get this value in PHP, but cleary this won't work;

`$trialDays = \Craft::$app->getGlobals()->getSetByHandle('freeTrialPeriodDays');`

I know it's simple, can't get the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your example, the `Global` handle is `globalWebsite` and the field handle is `freeTrialPeriodDays`.

So this should work in PHP:

```
$trialDays = \Craft::$app->getGlobals()->getSetByHandle('globalWebsite')->freeTrialPeriodDays;
```

You should probably do this in two steps so you can check that a `Global` has been returned before you try to query the field value on it:

```
$myGlobal = \Craft::$app->getGlobals()->getSetByHandle('globalWebsite');
if ($myGlobal) {
    $trialDays = $myGlobal->freeTrialPeriodDays;
} else {
    $trialDays = 'some default value';
}
```

This can be simplified using the null coalescing operator like this:

```
$trialDays = \Craft::$app->getGlobals()->getSetByHandle('globalWebsite')->freeTrialPeriodDays ?? 'some default value';
```

Comment: My first reflex would really be "Duh!" but instead I will simply say THANK YOU lol
Yeah, I knew it was going to look simple.
Thanks again.